# How can I solve continuous data being treated as separate entities when running logistic regression in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, logistic-regression

I am trying to run a logistic regression in R (purely for practice purposes). However I am encountering a few issues.
My main issue is that when I run the actual model, it treats my continuous variables separately. Meaning I might get the following output when I try to predict my categorical variable using something like age:

```
> Call:
> glm(formula = problem ~ age, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
> data = train)
> 
> Deviance Residuals: 
> Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
> -2.03933  -1.01077   0.00013   0.90052   1.48230  
> 
> Coefficients:
> Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
> (Intercept)  1.857e+01  6.523e+03   0.003    0.998
> age19       -1.787e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age21       -1.857e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age22       -3.713e+01  7.532e+03  -0.005    0.996
> age23       -1.857e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age24       -3.684e-07  7.532e+03   0.000    1.000
> age25       -3.679e-07  7.293e+03   0.000    1.000
> age26       -1.857e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age27       -1.718e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age28       -1.787e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age29       -1.897e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age30       -1.897e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age31       -1.857e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age32       -1.857e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age33       -1.787e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age34       -1.897e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age35       -1.772e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age36       -1.857e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age37       -1.747e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age38       -3.651e-07  7.532e+03   0.000    1.000
> age39       -3.644e-07  7.532e+03   0.000    1.000
> age40       -1.857e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age41       -1.834e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age42       -1.677e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age43       -1.885e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age44       -1.828e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age45       -3.687e-07  7.532e+03   0.000    1.000
> age46       -1.816e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age47       -1.816e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age48       -1.662e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age49       -1.718e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age50       -1.926e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age51       -1.787e+01  6.523e+03  -0.003    0.998
> age52       -3.690e-07  7.532e+03   0.000    1.000
> age53       -3.650e-07  7.989e+03   0.000    1.000
> age54       -3.683e-07  7.532e+03   0.000    1.000
> age55       -3.681e-07  7.989e+03   0.000    1.000
> age56       -3.689e-07  7.532e+03   0.000    1.000
> age57       -3.643e-07  7.293e+03   0.000    1.000
> age58       -3.643e-07  7.532e+03   0.000    1.000
> age59       -3.689e-07  7.293e+03   0.000    1.000
> age60       -3.643e-07  9.224e+03   0.000    1.000
> age62       -3.652e-07  7.989e+03   0.000    1.000
> age63       -3.681e-07  7.532e+03   0.000    1.000
> age65       -3.689e-07  9.224e+03   0.000    1.000
> age66       -3.682e-07  7.293e+03   0.000    1.000
> age68       -3.645e-07  9.224e+03   0.000    1.000
> 
> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
> 
> Null deviance: 247.64  on 199  degrees of freedom
> Residual deviance: 180.41  on 153  degrees of freedom
> AIC: 274.41
> 
> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 17
```

My code is below

```
> #loading packages
> 
> library(tidyverse)
> 
> view(rawdata)
> glimpse(rawdata)
> str(rawdata)
> str(id)
> 
> Setting data to factors
> rawdata$sex <- as.factor(rawdata$sex)
> rawdata$marital <- as.factor(rawdata$marital)
> rawdata$age <- as.factor(rawdata$age)
> rawdata$hourwnit <- as.factor(rawdata$hourwnit)
> rawdata$problem <- as.factor(rawdata$problem)
> rawdata$stayslprec <- as.factor(rawdata$stayslprec)
> rawdata$getsleprec <- as.factor(rawdata$getsleprec)
> 
> glimpse(rawdata)
> 
> bar charts
> 
> ggplot(data, aes(getsleprec, fill = marital)) +
> geom_bar() +
> coord_flip()
> 
> subsetting data
> 
> data <- subset(rawdata, select = c(1,2,3,4,15,28,48,49))
> newdata <- na.omit(data)
> newdata
> view(newdata)
> str(newdata)
> 
> train <- newdata[1:200,]
> test <- newdata[201:241,]
> 
> Logistic regression
> 
> model <- glm(problem ~ hourwnit, family=binomial(link='logit'),data=train)
> summary(model)
> view(train)
>
```

Running code again with a few different variables, the categorical ones look fine.

Comment: Sounds like your age variable may not be stored correctly - can you `dput(head(train))` and paste the result into the original question as an edit please?  It will let us see the structure of your data.

Comment: Age may be a factor and not integer/numeric in data set. Please show output of `str(train)`.

Comment: Yes, it looks like you are specifically changing age to a factor, when it should be left as a numeric variable.

Comment: Thanks, yes this is why. How do I set it to numeric? is it simply "as.numeric(data$age) ?

Comment: `as.numeric(as.character(data$age))` is the safe way to convert from factor to numeric. Though the better way would be to delete `rawdata$age <- as.factor(rawdata$age)` so it is never converted to factor in the first place and re-import your data, keeping it as numeric from the start.